# Sound on Windows 2000 Server

Tags: windows-service, windows-server-2000, windows-2000, audio

We have still some Windows 2000 Server / Advanced Server machines running.

Is it possible to install audio service or something? It does not seem to have sound capabilities (like the Windows 2000 Professional client machines do.)

If possible, how would I do this?

*edit*: We installed Service Pack 4 and the Usb 2.0 sound devices work fine since then.

Comment: Are you working so close to your servers that you would hear the sound? Are these real servers or workstations with a server OS?

Comment: Yes, close. And they are real servers :o (19 inch rack!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the servers have sound cards? If not, then that's the problem. You need to install a sound card and drivers before you can get audio capabilities.

Comment: No, they do not have sound card, but if I plug in an usb audio stick nothing happens. When I plug in the same stick to a newer windows it installs it automatically. MAybe I should update the question and give more details about the usb stuff? And maybe this is an usb question? (But anyway there is no sound or audio service in the services screen)

Comment: Well then the answer is to install the driver for the usb audio stick (whatever that is) or to install a sound card.

Comment: joe, we had to install the latest service pack (sp4) and this contained usb 2.0 drivers. now we can plug in usb sound device and it works. thank you for showing me the direction!

Comment: Glad to help...